# New added color in my iPhone application stop syncing it from google calendar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, synchronization, google-calendar-api

I am developing a application for iPhone with the syncing feature for google calendar in it.what i am doing is that 
,I add some new color in my app.Now i launch the app and assign the new color to the events and sync it with google ,but the application does not sync and give error messages that color is invalid.I want to know that ,is there 
any restriction on calendar color.Or what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [API specs](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/reference.html#gCalcolor) you are limited to 1 of 21 predefined colors.